# Instead of someone (Choice of phrase)

Tags: meaning, difference, phrase-choice

If I am somewhere *on behalf of someone* or *to represent someone* which way is best to say it in formal English?

- I'm here in the name of Daniel Swift.
- I'm here in Daniel Swift's name.
- I'm here under Daniel Swift's name.

Is there a difference between the three?

Is it better to say:

- I'm here to represent Daniel Swift.
- I'm here on behalf of Daniel Swift.

Comment: it's all about context. A lawyer might say **represent** but a friend or colleague would probably not. In a real situation, you would probably start of by saying what you want to do, then refer Daniel Swift using the appropriate preposition. For example, "I'm here to check the artwork that you are doing **for** Daniel Swift"  or "I'm here to drop off an order **from** Daniel Swift". If it's anything more complicated than this, you would probably need a letter of representation or even a power of attorney, and that will explain exactly what you are authorised to do, for whom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to express this situation is

> I'm here ***on behalf*** of Daniel Swift.
>   I'm here ***to represent*** Daniel Swift.
>   I'm here ***representing*** Daniel Swift.
>   I'm here ***in place of*** Daniel Swift.
>   I'm here ***as proxy for*** Daniel Swift.
>   I'm here ***substituting*** for Daniel Swift.

Usually the phrase

> in the name of

is not used, since you are representing the person and not just their name.